# Rails collection_select: using 'prompt' with logic - is there a better way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I am using a form_tag to create my own search facility on a site displaying items.

I have a collection_select which lists locations of the items. I initially used `prompt: 'n/a'` to display 'n/a' without adding 'n/a' into the list of locations and then tried to use `select: params[:search][:location]` to keep the selection in the list after submitting. Basically I could get one of them to work at a time. Never both. I have written a work-around below:

`<%= collection_select(:search, :location, Item::LOCATIONS, :to_s, :titleize, prompt: (@location ? params[:search][:location] : 'n/a')) %>`

This is working but it feels wrong. I have obviously created a variable called `@location` in the controller for when the params exist and then added logic into the collection_select tag.

Any cleaner solutions to this would be appreciated. I am very new to Rails (and coding!) so trying to learn best practices.

Comment: why you want logical prompt

Comment: is that a question? as in, why do i want it?

Comment: I want to use the select option, but it wouldnt work, that's why i'm using a logical prompt